# How can I create a table from a textarea?

Tags: php, mysql

Edited and Solved (Thanks to Prix)

Here is the Full Script, An amazing Visitor Tracker: https://github.com/solarisedesign/Visitor-Tracker-PHP-MySQL

I found a solution with the help of user Prix! An amazing and awesome person! He helped me create a new SQL Table!

Here is an image of an example I found online, and this is how I want to build it:

[image]

**Here is an image of the new Database by Prix:**
[image]

Direct Link to the Database query, by Prix: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bc83/5/0

Many thanks to Prix for helping me out....... Check the full Topic below... Thank you

My Question was:

I am simply trying to create my own script for users to log Visitor IPs and also go in and Track who was visiting their site and everything will be logged inside a MySQL database!

When launching the script, they users will be asked to choose a Name inside a "textarea".
So when a user picks a name and clicks on CREATE URL, then the script will create a SQL database table called `test`. Right now the Script is only used for 1 Person or user! But I want to make it available for everyone, so users only have to visit our site and simply create a user, and all the files and tables will be automatically added in the folder and ready for use.

I want to know how I can create a Table for each user that choose a name in `textarea`! So when a user chooses the name "mike" in the `textarea`, then the script should create a table named "mike" and simply add the rest of the tables inside the table "mike"!

The textarea is called "$name" in the sql code below, and when I add "$name" infront of the this part:

```
CREATE TABLE $name
```

Then I simply get an error. I don't know how to add the `textarea` so it can create the same table as the name chosen in the text area:

This is my full script:

```
<form action="" method="post" >
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center">Please choose a Folder or Name?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="text" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo " "; 
        echo "Conguradulations. Your new URL is sucessfully created.!"; 
        echo " ";
        echo " ";
        echo "Your new URL name is $name"; 
    }
    $dbhost = 'host';
    $dbuser = 'dbuser';
    $dbpass = 'dbpass';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE test('.
     'entry_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, '.
     'visitor_id int(11) default NULL, '.
     'ip_address varchar(15) NOT NULL, '.
     'page_name text, '.
     'query_string text, '.
     'timestamp timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '.
     'PRIMARY KEY  ( entry_id ), '.
     'KEY visitor_id ( visitor_id , timestamp )) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;';

    mysql_select_db('dbname');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_query($sql,$conn);
?>
```

So the script above has the everything in it and done. I just need help to attach the `textarea` so it can create the a table in MySQL using the text from the textarea!

I was thinking that this could help me out, and if someone could help me create a code from that to help me out.

Comment: I think you should really rethink your need for new tables with each addition. You might run into table name collisions, and also, you would then need to enforce MySQL table naming validations?  Also, why are you giving success messages before the query is even successful?  Seems odd. Finally, you should not be using `mysql_*` functions for any new code as these functions are deprecated. take a look at using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @Prix, It finally worked MAte! The new one you added ' . $name . ', worked awesome! But when I load the page, I get this error >> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(entry_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, visitor_id int(11) default NULL, ip_a' at line 1... God bless

Comment: Prix, Wow! Thank you so much Prix! I will be working on it immediatly.. You really saved me from all this! Your simply the best! I am pretty new in here done know how to add REP, but you just got 10+ rep for your amazing help and efforts since yesterday! God bless you mate! I will be adding update about it!